# How can I get the full link from beautifulsoup instead of only the internal link

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am new to python. I am building a crawler for the company I work for. Crawling its website, there is a internal link that is not in the link format that it is used to. How can I get the entire link instead of the directory only. If I was not too clear, please run the code that I made bellow:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

web_page_string = []

def get_first_page(seed):
    response = urllib2.urlopen(seed)
    web_page = response.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(web_page)
    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        print (link.get('href'))
    print soup


print get_first_page('http://www.fashionroom.com.br')
print web_page_string
```

Comment: What do you mean by entire link?

Comment: `print seed + '/' + link.get('href')`?

Comment: I wanted to get htt://www.fashionroom.com.br/indexnew.html in the case above. Instead, I just got indexnew.html

Answer (score 0):

Tks everyone for the answers I tried to put an if in the script. If anyone sees a potential problem with something I will find in the future, pls let me know

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

web_page_string = []

def get_first_page(seed):
    response = urllib2.urlopen(seed)
    web_page = response.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(web_page)
    final_page_string = soup.get_text()
    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        if (link.get('href'))[0:4]=='http':
            print (link.get('href'))
        else:
            print seed+'/'+(link.get('href'))
    print final_page_string


print get_first_page('http://www.fashionroom.com.br')
print web_page_string
```